# In python when I use 'Reply' function for outlook mail item the previous conversation is not appending

Tags: python

I am using python 3.7.0

Eg:-

> 1. Person 'A' sent mail to me with text :- "Test mail".
> 2. Person 'B' received the mail and replied with body :- "Thanks for the information. Please attach logs"
> 3. Person 'A' received the mail with new body message mentioned in step-2. The body message mentioned in step-1 is not appearing in the
>      mail.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages=inbox.items
msg=messages.GetLast()

reply=msg.Reply()
reply.Body = "Thanks for the information. Please attach logs"
reply.Send
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can replay the mail and keep previous conversations:

```
    reply.Body = "Thanks for the information. Please attach logs" + reply.Body
    reply.Send()
```